# Is it possible with a vertical multiline ChipGroup where there is one chip per line?

Tags: android, material-design, android-chips

I'm trying to create a `ChipGroup` that is vertically aligned and contains a max of one item per row? Like so:

[image: item alignment example]

So that when you add a new `Chip` to the group it will align itself to either the bottom or the top (doesn't matter much).

I've tried forcing a `max-width: 120dp` (or something similar with a large value) with not much luck.

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is **Pass ArrayList** to chip group and **SORT** that ArrayList by string length. and update all list when new item added or remove